# Can I 'link' two set of data in SQL and retrieve values against both to compare?

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested, subquery

Goal: to compare the string in a field (Dispatcher) in Table C1+2 against two strings in Table A (DF code and MD code).

Table A: Contains DFCode and MDCode (this table only exists to link these two strings together)
Table B: Contains All codes (MD and DF types) and an ItemID for each code
TableC1+2: Contains Itemcode and Dispatcher for each code.

Novice here. Table C contains all the dispatchers against an ItemID, Table B contains all Codes and ItemIDs. I want to see the two codes with their dispatchers side by side. It seems simple but I can't figure out how to look up the MDCode in table B and link it through to the dispatcher in TableC

```
select 
    DF Code,
    MD Code,    
    DF Dispatcher,          
    MD Dispatcher
from TableA
      LEFT JOIN TableC1
      LEFT JOIN TableC2
      LEFT JOIN TableB
```

Once I have the above cracked I'll add a "Where DFDispatcher and MDDispatcher do not match". I expect to see four columns of results showing the DFCode, the MDCode and the two Dispatcher fields which do not match.

Expected result:

DFCode|MDCode|DFDispatcher|MDDispatcher

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. (Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you start.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [start here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: Still not clear enough in your question, I've tried drawing an entity diagram on paper of what you're asking but it isn't clear what data is in which table, particularly your MD and DF values. Can you be very clear about which table has which column name and which table has MD and DF values in those columns.